# How to update HTTP status code based on json response for request type is JSON

Tags: python, postman, odoo, odoo-12, rest

how to get JSON response with a custom message and HTTP status code as per the response-
My requested path is

```py
@http.route("/api/product/create", type="json", auth="none", methods=["POST"], csrf=False)
def post(self, **payload):
    payload = payload.get("payload", {})
    model = request.env['product.template']
    resource = request.env[model.model].create(payload)
    data = resource.read()
    if resource: 
        return valid_response(data) 
    else:
        return valid_response(data)
```

And i got always status "200 Ok" with json response body

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": null,
    "result": "<Response 184 bytes [200 OK]>"
}
```

how can I get a proper result and HTTP status code? I want to show the HTTP status code "201 Created" for the created records.

Comment: You have to post more code.

Comment: @http.route("/api/product/create", type="json", auth="none", methods=["POST"], csrf=False)
    def post(self, **payload):
        payload = payload.get("payload", {})
        model = request.env['product.template']
         resource = request.env[model.model].create(payload)
         data = resource.read()
         if resource:
                return valid_response(data)
         else:
                return valid_response(data)